# upload blob to google drive using google drive api in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, fetch-api

i am able to upload blob to google drive using google drive api, but failing to assign filename and filepath

```
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media',{
    method:'post',body:imgBlob,headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'image/webp',
        'Content-Disposition':`attachment;filename=${fileName}`,
        'Authorization':`Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
}).then(req=>req.json()).then(res=>console.log(res)).catch(error=>console.log(error))
```

please assist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to upload a blob to Google Drive by giving the file metadata of the filename and the folder using the fetch API of Javascript
- Your access token can be used for uploading a file to Google Drive.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script

```js
const folderId = "###"; // Please set your folder ID.
const filename = "###"; // Please set filename on Google Drive.
const accessToken = "###"; // Please set your access token.

const form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify({ name: fileName, parents: [folderId] })], { type: 'application/json' }));
form.append('file', imgBlob);
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
  body: form
}).then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res));
```

##### Note:

- In this case, the maximum file size is 5 MB. If you want to upload a large file size, please use the resumable upload. Please be careful about this.
- If the destination folder is in the shared Drive, please add `supportsAllDrives=true` to the query parameter of the endpoint.

#### Reference:

- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads)

Comment: thank you very much for the quick response Tanaike, is there any way to auth and get code without consent screen when code become invalid

Comment: @Sikki Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `is there any way to auth and get code without consent screen when code become invalid`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. So, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?