# Submitting form data that includes files/images to a back end server function in google app script

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script

As the title states, I'm trying to submit some form data to a back end server function to handle that data and do what I want with it. This data will also occasionally hold either images or files. The files and image handling is what I'm having the most trouble with. The issue I'm running in to is that, because this is in google app script, all of the more common ways of doing this, such as using the `File` API, is not available to me, and I'm not sure of similar methodologies to the `File` API in google app script.

What's supposed to happen after the form is successfully submitted is that all of the information, besides the files and images are saved to a google sheet, and an email is sent out, populated with all of the data from the form. Everything worked successfully until I needed to potentially have files or images sent with the email as well.

My thought process was, on the front-end, have the images saved to google drive, and then, when I needed them in the code, I could pull them out of the folder after passing their file IDs down to the back end function. Pulling them from their file IDs would be done in the back end server function. The issue is just actually getting the files saved INTO google drive, as nothing I've done has been successful so far. I am also open to other suggestions.

I haven't been able to find a suitable solution anywhere, and would really appreciate some assistance. I can provide further details as necessary. Below is my front end function:

```
function saveAlert(){
    let out = []
    //Setting controls object to each of the html input elements in the form
    let controls = {
      alertSelect: document.getElementById('alertSelect'),
      alertLocation: document.getElementById('alertLocation'),
      alertCode: document.getElementById('alertCode'),
      servicesAffected: document.getElementById('servicesAffected'),
      alertAddress: document.getElementById('alertAddress'),
      alertSubject: document.getElementById('alertSubject'),
      alertBody: tinymce.activeEditor.getContent(),
      alertDate: document.getElementById('alertDate'),
      alertEndDate: document.getElementById('alertEndDate'),
      imageUpload: document.getElementById('imageUpload'),
      userEmail: document.getElementById('userEmail'),
    }
    //If-check to make sure form is filled out properly
    if(validateInput(controls)){
      let modalSpinner = document.getElementById('modalSpinner')
      modalSpinner.hidden = false
      let alertDateFinal = controls.alertDate.value.replaceAll('-','/')
      let alertEndDateFinal = controls.alertEndDate.value.replaceAll('-','/')
      alertDate.value === '' ? new Date(alertDateFinal).toLocaleDateString() : new Date(alertDateFinal)
      alertEndDate.value === '' ? new Date(alertEndDateFinal).toLocaleDateString() : new Date(alertEndDateFinal)
      
      //My attempt
      let fileInput = controls.imageUpload;
      let formData = new FormData();

      for (let i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        let file = fileInput.files[i];
        formData.append('images[]', file, file.name);
      }

      //Creating new record based on values in the controls object
      let record = {
        'Alert Type': controls.alertSelect.value,
        'Alert Location': controls.alertLocation.value,
        'Alert Code': controls.alertCode.value,
        'Services Affected': controls.servicesAffected.value,
        'Alert Address': controls.alertAddress.value,
        'Alert Subject': controls.alertSubject.value,
        'Alert Details': controls.alertBody,
        'Alert Date': alertDateFinal,
        'Alert End Date': alertEndDateFinal,
        'User Email': controls.userEmail.value,
        //This causes an error in the code
        'Images': formData,
        'Alert Active': true
      }
    
      //Pushing the record to the server side function 'saveAlerts()', which adds the alert created from the form to the google sheet
      out.push(record)      
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(clearForm).saveAlerts(out)
      
    } else{
      window.alert('Please Check Input')
    }
  }
```

And this is my server side function. I haven't updated anything yet, as I haven't been able to pass the files/images to it successfully, but it's important for context:

```
function saveAlerts(data) {
  Logger.log(data)
  //Gets all the data in the alerts sheet
  let sheetData = alerts.getDataRange().getDisplayValues()
  //Get keys from the first row of the sheet
  let keys = sheetData[0]
  //For each alert in the array, create a temporary array containing the values for each column in the sheet
  data.forEach(el => {
    let temp = []
    keys.forEach(key => {
      temp.push(el[key])
    })
    //Append the temporary array as a new row in the sheet
    alerts.appendRow(temp)
  })

  let template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('htmlEmail');
  template.data = data;
  template.alertDetails = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(data[0]['Alert Details']).getContent()
  let message = template.evaluate().getContent();

  //Takes the data variable and pulls out the the 'Alert Subject' and 'Alert Details', and appends them to an email that is sent out when the form is submitted
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'YOUR EMAIL',
    subject: `${data[0]['Alert Subject']}`,
    htmlBody: message,
    replyTo: `${data[0]['User Email']}`
  })
}
```

To summarize, I'm looking for guidance on how to properly handle the images submitted with the form, and how I can save them to my google drive server, or is this even possible in a simple enough way without utilizing google cloud?

Thank you for any assistance

Comment: What's you question?

Comment: @Cooper Sorry, didn't recognize I didn't ask, but I know it's much more easy using Google Cloud, but I'm trying to determine if it's possible without using google cloud to basically save images from a form submitted into a server, and then somehow pass those image's ID's to a different back end function to attach them to an email. Does all that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing the whole Form Object to the Server Function. As per Google's documentation:

> If you call a server function with a form element as a parameter, the form becomes a single object with field names as keys and field values as values. The values are all converted to strings, except for the contents of file-input fields, which become Blob objects.

You'll need to make sure that the input fields are named as in the example so that you can use it in Apps Script like this:

- index.html

```html
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <input name="myFile" type="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

- JavaScript in index.html

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).processForm(formObject);
      }
```

- Code.gs

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var formBlob = formObject.myFile;
  var driveFile = DriveApp.createFile(formBlob);
  return driveFile.getUrl();
}
```

The rest of the fields would also need to have the `name` property and reference it like `formObject.alertSelect`

---

Google Documentation:

- HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions - [Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms)

---

## Edit:

I've created this example based on your code and an [answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75425414/19602805), this first uploads all files saved in the `imageUpload` element and save their new Google Drive IDs to an array that will then be passed to the Server Script:

```
  <script>
    var data = <?!= JSON.stringify(dataFromServerTemplate) ?>
    async function saveAlert(formObject){
     
      let out = []
    
      let fileInput = document.getElementById("imageUpload");

      let formData = new FormData();
      let accessToken = data.OAuthToken;
      let folderId = "A_FOLDER_ID"; // Optional
      let imageIds = [];


      for (let i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        let file = fileInput.files[i];
        console.log(file);
        formData.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify({ name: file.name, parents: [folderId] })], { type: 'application/json' }));
        formData.append('file', file);

        await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
          body: formData
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(res => imageIds.push(res.id));
        formData = new FormData();
      }

      let record = {
        'Alert Type': "controls.alertSelect.value",
        'Alert Location': "controls.alertLocation.value",
        'Alert Code': "controls.alertCode.value",
        'Services Affected': "controls.servicesAffected.value",
        'Alert Address': "controls.alertAddress.value",
        'Alert Subject': "controls.alertSubject.value",
        'Alert Details': "controls.alertBody",
        'Alert Date': "alertDateFinal",
        'Alert End Date': "alertEndDateFinal",
        'User Email': "controls.userEmail.value",
        //This causes an error in the code
        'Images': imageIds,
        'Alert Active': true
      }

      out.push(record)      
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(clearForm).saveAlerts(out)
    }
  </script>
```

Note that the `doGet()` function in `Code.gs` needs to pass the Script's OAuth token as a parameter:

```
function doGet(e) {
  htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index.html');
  htmlTemplate.dataFromServerTemplate = { OAuthToken : ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() };
  return htmlTemplate.evaluate();
  
}
```

The Ids will be available at `data[0].Images`

Comment: I guess part of my issue with this is that I don't explicitly declare a form in the HTML document, but instead it's a modal with inputs. That's why I can't do it in that specific way.

Comment: I added another option to my answer.

Comment: So I wanted to follow up my previous comment, but I've done something similar to this solution, however it unfortunately, does not work because of CORS policy is blocking it, so the next best solution I've found is to proxy to my server side function that then sends to the google drive (Google's server basically). Unfortunately I don't know how I would proxy to my back end in google app script