# Saving an image to google drive through google app script without using the Drive API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

(This might be irrelevant, but it is important for background purposes)
I have a form that is submitted by users that can contain an image. When this form is submitted, an email is sent out with all of the relevant information from the submitted form, including the image that was attached to the form. The image is attached to the email as an attachment. To get the image as an attachment to the email, when the form is submitted, the image is saved to a google drive folder, and its id is returned. The id is used in a separate function to basically find the image in google drive, and attach it to the email.

(My specific issue)
I am trying to save an image to a google drive folder without using the Drive API (as I'm not allowed to for company reasons). I've determined that the most effective methodology in my case is to use a server-side proxy function to avoid a CORS based error. (Someone please correct me if I'm wrong with how I'm describing this) When a user submits a form on my front end, the image file uploaded is sent to my app script back end, which is then sent to my google drive. The issue I'm encountering is, once again, a CORS-policy error, but this time my error is with my own web app restricting me from sending the data to the back end. I tried to rectify this by setting headers that allow specific information, but it is not working. I'm thinking this is because `.setHeaders()` does not work in App Script, or, even though it's "my" web app, it's still being hosted by google, so they'll still restrict it. I will list my front-end and back-end code below. I can provide any further details as necessary.

Front End Code:

```
<script>
  function saveAlert() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(saveNewAlert).getPayload()
  }
  
  //takes user input from a modal dialog form and sends it to a server-side function named saveAlerts() for processing and storage in a Google Sheet
  async function saveNewAlert(data){
    let out = []
    
    //Setting controls object to each of the html input elements in the form
    let controls = {
      alertSelect: document.getElementById('alertSelect'),
      alertLocation: document.getElementById('alertLocation'),
      alertCode: document.getElementById('alertCode'),
      servicesAffected: document.getElementById('servicesAffected'),
      alertAddress: document.getElementById('alertAddress'),
      alertSubject: document.getElementById('alertSubject'),
      alertBody: tinymce.activeEditor.getContent(),
      alertDate: document.getElementById('alertDate'),
      alertEndDate: document.getElementById('alertEndDate'),
      userEmail: document.getElementById('userEmail'),
      imageUpload: document.getElementById('imageUpload')
    }

    //If-check to make sure form is filled out properly
    if(validateInput(controls)){
      let modalSpinner = document.getElementById('modalSpinner')
      modalSpinner.hidden = false
      let alertDateFinal = controls.alertDate.value.replaceAll('-','/')
      let alertEndDateFinal = controls.alertEndDate.value.replaceAll('-','/')
      alertDate.value === '' ? new Date(alertDateFinal).toLocaleDateString() : new Date(alertDateFinal)
      alertEndDate.value === '' ? new Date(alertEndDateFinal).toLocaleDateString() : new Date(alertEndDateFinal)

      let accessToken = data.accessToken
      webAppUrl = data.webAppUrl
      let imageIds = []
      let formData = new FormData()

      for(let i = 0; i < imageUpload.files.length; i++){
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('imageFile', imageUpload.files[i])

        await fetch(webAppUrl + '?action=uploadImage', {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'cors',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
          },
          body: formData
        })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(fileId => {
          imageIds.push(fileId)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error saving files', error)
        })
      }

      //Creating new record based on values in the controls object
      let record = {
        'Alert Type': controls.alertSelect.value,
        'Alert Location': controls.alertLocation.value,
        'Alert Code': controls.alertCode.value,
        'Services Affected': controls.servicesAffected.value,
        'Alert Address': controls.alertAddress.value,
        'Alert Subject': controls.alertSubject.value,
        'Alert Details': controls.alertBody,
        'Alert Date': alertDateFinal,
        'Alert End Date': alertEndDateFinal,
        'User Email': controls.userEmail.value,
        'Alert Active': true,
        // 'Images': imageIds
      }

      //Pushing the record to the server side function 'saveAlerts()', which adds the alert created from the form to the google sheet
      out.push(record)      
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(clearForm).saveAlerts(out)
      
    } else{
      window.alert('Please Check Input')
    }
  }
</script>
```

Back End Code:

```
function doPost(e){
  if(e.parameter.action === 'uploadImage'){
    let imageFile = e.parameter.imageFile
    let fileId = saveImageToDrive(imageFile)

    let headers = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization'
    }

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(fileId).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT).setHeaders(headers)
  }
}
```

Relevant Function `.getPayload()`

```
function getPayload() {
  const payload = {
    accessToken: ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    webAppUrl: ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
  }

  return payload
}
```

This function returns a token to allow access to google APIs (I believe I need it here, but am unsure), and the web app URL. I return the web app URL as well because when testing, the URL changes, so I just capture the current URL and use that instead of setting a pre-defined one.

I did not have this previously, but here is the `saveImageToDrive()` function:

```
function saveImageToDrive(imageFile) {
  var fileName = imageFile.getName(); // Assuming imageFile is a File object
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(imgFolderID);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(imageFile);

  return newFile.getId(); // Return the ID of the saved file
}
```

In a comment, I also specified that a co-worker was able to get around the CORS issue but using `XMLHttpRequst()`. Here is the function he used:

```
let fr = new FileReader()
const { fileName, fileSize, fileType } = fr

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&supportsAllDrives=true")
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + accessToken)
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "multipart/form-data")
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Upload-Content-Type', fileType)
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Upload-Content-Length', fileSize)
xhr.onload = () => {
  var location = xhr.getResponseHeader("location")
  var upr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  fr.progel.hidden = false
  upr.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
    var stat = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100
    fr.progel.firstElementChild.style.width = stat + '%'
  }
  upr.open("PUT", location)
  upr.send(fr.result)
  upr.onload = () => {
    fr.spinel.hidden = true
    fr.progel.hidden = true
  }
}
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ parents: [imgFolderID], name: fileName }))
```

Comment: As far as I know, it would be required to use the Drive API, did you tested one of these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76327104/17926478)?

Comment: @LorenaGomez I have. However, I do know it's possible because I have co-worker who was capable of doing the same thing without having the Drive API enabled for his App Script project. He did it through an ```XMLHttpRequest()```. I will add that as well so that people have a point of reference as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I've come to learn, the XML way it was previously done is no longer a valid way of doing it in google app script. Thankfully, I found a different way of doing it that allows me to avoid a CORS policy error, and in fact doesn't even need an access token. The updated code is as follows:

Front End:

```
  //takes user input from a modal dialog form and sends it to a server-side function named saveAlerts() for processing and storage in a Google Sheet
  function saveAlert() {
    let out = []

    //Setting controls object to each of the html input elements in the form
    let controls = {
      alertSelect: document.getElementById('alertSelect'),
      alertLocation: document.getElementById('alertLocation'),
      alertCode: document.getElementById('alertCode'),
      servicesAffected: document.getElementById('servicesAffected'),
      alertAddress: document.getElementById('alertAddress'),
      alertSubject: document.getElementById('alertSubject'),
      alertBody: tinymce.activeEditor.getContent(),
      alertDate: document.getElementById('alertDate'),
      alertEndDate: document.getElementById('alertEndDate'),
      userEmail: document.getElementById('userEmail'),
      imageUpload: document.getElementById('imageUpload')
    }

    //If-check to make sure form is filled out properly
    if (validateInput(controls)) {
      let modalSpinner = document.getElementById('modalSpinner')
      modalSpinner.hidden = false
      let alertDateFinal = controls.alertDate.value.replaceAll('-', '/')
      let alertEndDateFinal = controls.alertEndDate.value.replaceAll('-', '/')
      alertDate.value === '' ? new Date(alertDateFinal).toLocaleDateString() : new Date(alertDateFinal)
      alertEndDate.value === '' ? new Date(alertEndDateFinal).toLocaleDateString() : new Date(alertEndDateFinal)

      let files = imageUpload.files

      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        let file = files[i];
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(file) {
          return function(e) {
            let dataUrl = e.target.result;
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
              alert("Image uploaded successfully!");
            }).uploadImage(file.name, dataUrl);
          };
        })(file);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
     
      //Creating new record based on values in the controls object
      let record = {
        'Alert Type': controls.alertSelect.value,
        'Alert Location': controls.alertLocation.value,
        'Alert Code': controls.alertCode.value,
        'Services Affected': controls.servicesAffected.value,
        'Alert Address': controls.alertAddress.value,
        'Alert Subject': controls.alertSubject.value,
        'Alert Details': controls.alertBody,
        'Alert Date': alertDateFinal,
        'Alert End Date': alertEndDateFinal,
        'User Email': controls.userEmail.value,
        'Alert Active': true,
        // 'Images': imageIds
      }

      //Pushing the record to the server side function 'saveAlerts()', which adds the alert created from the form to the google sheet
      out.push(record)
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(clearForm).saveAlerts(out)

    } else {
      window.alert('Please Check Input')
    }
  }
```

Back End:

```
function uploadImage(fileName, dataURL) {
  let allowedExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']
  let fileExtension = fileName.split('.')[1]
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(imgFolderID)
  let blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(dataURL.split(',')[1]), "", fileName)
  let file = folder.createFile(blob)
  
  return file.getId()
}
```

That is all it is interestingly enough. If you want it to work with all file types, just replace `image/jpeg` with `""` and it should work with all file types. This does not accomplish my original task of attaching it to an email, but that was not intention of this question.